# Finding a specific package

Tags: debian-wheezy

I have a very old system:

```
# uname -a
Linux [REMOVED] 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.96-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I need to update it to the latest available kernel version.  For example, I'm trying to find 3.2.101-1 or newer.

Shouldn't this be the `linux-image` package and I should find it here?
http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian-security/pool/updates/main/l/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm blind, but still don't understand the difference between these two "version numbers":

linux-image-`3.2.0-6`-amd64_`3.2.102-1`_amd64.deb

I'll keep searching.

The latest/greatest kernel for Wheezy seems to be here:
http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian-security/pool/updates/main/l/linux/